# How to count a row with oracle sql in php?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, count

i want to count how much rows data in database. show me some code to count it with oracle sql in php

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS COUNT 
FROM AUDIT_LOG_HEADER A 
WHERE 
    A.AUDIT_REFERENCE_NO LIKE 'IA-19%' 
    AND (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM AUDIT_LOG_DETAIL 
        WHERE AUDIT_LOG_NUMBER = A.AUDIT_LOG_NUMBER
    ) > 0
```

I already have tried using count function there. but i think that my query is not right.

Comment: Do you have something against making the code readable?    Go back and look at who edited the formatting of your query. Unfortunately, someone edited his edit, but I’d go back through the edits to see what everyone is doing to make it easier to read.

Comment: "i think that my query is not right"... why? Do you need a different result? If so, which one? Or are you having an error? and if so, which one? As is, it's hard to understand what you need and why your code is not good for that. Please post some more informations to help people to help you

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CNT) AS CNT
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN COUNT(D.AUDIT_LOG_NUMBER) OVER(
                    PARTITION BY A.AUDIT_LOG_NUMBER
                ) > 0 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END AS CNT
        FROM
            AUDIT_LOG_HEADER A
            JOIN AUDIT_LOG_DETAIL D ON ( D.AUDIT_LOG_NUMBER = A.AUDIT_LOG_NUMBER )
        WHERE
            A.AUDIT_REFERENCE_NO LIKE 'IA-19%'
    );
```

-- Query updated

Cheers!!

Comment: I think my previous query must be giving an error: `ORA-30483: window functions are not allowed here`. Hence, I have updated the answer now. Please check